# Fill barchart with patterns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently working on plotting a bar chart. For easier readability and to make the different bars distinguishable after b&w-printing I want to plot the bars using different patterns and if at all possible different colors and patterns similar to [this](http://www.burningcutlery.com/derek/bargraph/cluster-pattern.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCJzr.png). Is this possible while using pandas or matplotlib? If so, are there pattern palettes similar to color palettes?
My current code looks like this

```
df.transpose().plot.bar(width=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Google held the answer :) Try passing `hatch='/'` to `bar()`.

All hatch options ([from here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)): `['/' | '' | '|' | '-' | '+' | 'x' | 'o' | 'O' | '.' | '*']`

Demo:
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html